# loop a recordset and add to Dictionary/Collection: item key exists

Tags: ms-access, vba

First vba/access project and for some reason, I can't seem to add an item to collection or dictionary through looping:

```
     Dim current_stock As Scripting.Dictionary

     Set current_stock = New Scripting.Dictionary

current_stocks_sql = "SELECT id, size,stock FROM bags"

 Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(current_stocks_sql)
' On Error Resume Next
 Do While Not rs.EOF
 current_stock.add rs!id, rs!stock
 MsgBox rs!id ' gives 1,2,3 correctly
 rs.MoveNext

 Loop
 'On Error GoTo 0

 rs.Close
```

when it reaches to id 2, it gives error item key exists already.

Answer (score 6):

`Dictionary.Add` allows you to store objects as keys.

`Dictionary.Add rs!id, rs!stock` doesn't add two values to the dictionary, but two field objects, the ID field and the stock field.

After moving to the next record, the field objects are still the same, thus you get an *Item key already exists* error.

Add the values instead of the field objects:

```
current_stock.add rs!id.Value, rs!stock.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who came to this page looking for a function that will basically convert the record set into a collection of dictionaries. Here is a function

```vb
Function sql_results(ByVal q As String) As Collection
    Dim myConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Set myConn = db_conn() ' this is a custom function of mine that connects to ' my database 
    
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = myConn.Execute(q)
    
    Dim coll As New Collection
    Dim dic As New Dictionary
     
    Do Until rs.EOF ' looping through the record set (the rows that are returned ' from the query
        Set dic = New Dictionary
        For Each Field In rs.Fields ' field = column
          dic.Add Field.Name, Field.value  ' every column has a name, every  'field has a value
        Next Field ' next column
        coll.Add dic 
        rs.MoveNext 'next row
    Loop
    Set sql_results = coll
End Function
```

If anyone needs more clarification, please feel free to comment, or if you know of a page that this answer is more needed, link it.

*disclaimer, ideally if you have a large dataset converting it into a collection dictionary would not be the smartest memory management thing to do